# Number of segments that can be in main memory at certain instant

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

"Consider a memory management system based on segments, with 32 bits of virtual addressing space, with 3 bits (the most significant) for segment identification. Is it possible for the total number of segments present in the main memory, at a given time, of the machine to be greater than 8?"
The answer is YES. Why if 2^3 == 8? Is it because it is 8 for each running process?

Why if 2^3 == 8? Is it because it is 8 for each running process?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is nonsensical because segments are identified using registers on every system I am aware of. If the "segment" is identified using part of the address then you are not using a segmented system.

Because the question asks for the number of segments per system (and not process) there could be any number of segments as you suggest.